# PHP Equivalent of sha1.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)

Tags: base64, sha1, cryptojs

I am converting a JS script into PHP.
The script uses the CryptoJS library and generates a hash using the following line:

```
var sha1 = CryptoJS.SHA1("message");
var sig = sha1.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

I have tried this php code

```
$sha1 = sha1("message");
$sig = base64_encode($sha1);
```

But the signature isn't the same, it's longer in php.

Your help is very much appreciated and needed !

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just needed to set $raw_output to true in the sha1 function !

```
$sha1 = sha1("message", true);
```

Now I look silly